# Confidence Interval in Monte Carlo integration

Tags: confidence-interval, variance, monte-carlo, integral

I want to integrate
$\int_{\mathbb{R}_+}\mathbb{1}_A(x) d\mathbb{P}(x)$, in other words I am interested in $\mathbb{P}(A)$. I did this numerically with two Monte Carlo steps.

First, I drew, say a sample of $10^3$ ($\mathbb{P}$-distributed). From this sample I calculated the mean. Repeating this $N$ times, i got a new mean (better) and calculated the 95% confidence interval using the variance of these $N$ estimates for $\mathbb{P}(A)$ with the Student-t distribution.

I see now, that some values do not fall into the confidence intervals (too many to be random). So I fear that my approach is flawed and underestimates the variance. Of course, there is always the possibility of having a wrong implementation. But then I increased the number of repetitions dramatically and it looked better.

I am not sure what to do. What is the standard procedure to compute the confidence interval here? Maybe using a $\sigma$-error/Chebyshev-inequality, i.e. just one step, not two? I am grateful for any hints.

Comment: The problem of this procedure is that the distribution of the estimators can be skewed and/or heavy tailed. Why don't you use a quantile-type confidence interval instead? This is, using the sample of estimators you have obtained, calculate for example the $0.025$ and $0.975$ quantiles.

Comment: You mean just sample once (some large number) - which is  a Binomial sample and use the quantiles?

Comment: Yes, but I do not see how this would be a Binomial sample. Let me check if I understand. You have $N$ estimators of ${\mathbb P}(A)$ based on the same number of samples of size $10^3$, right?

Comment: Correct. More specifically I want to know $\mathbb{P}(X_T>x)$ for some jump process (heavy tailed jumps). So each estimator just runs $10^3$ sample paths - it is like hit if $X_T>x$ and no hit if it is below the threshold.

Comment: OK, so since the Binomial is stable under convolution, I can use e.g. Wald's method to do that. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to guarantee a confidence interval irrespective of the (unknown) P(A), you could use inverse binomial sampling. It is a sequential stopping rule that automatically adapts sample size (N) to obtain a prescribed confidence interval. If interested see: arxiv.org/abs/0809.2402 or a simpler version: oa.upm.es/4350

Comment: What are you talking about ? you should simply use user10525 empirical method : more relevant because not relying on any gaussian asumption.

Comment: The CI coverage will be too low if the MC samples are positively serially correlated, which would be the case if they were generated with MCMC and not suitably thinned.

Comment: @whuber forget about thinning, it does not help that much (e.g. http://doingbayesiandataanalysis.blogspot.com/2011/11/thinning-to-reduce-autocorrelation.html)